# Why registry and setter values are cleared in toolbar block?

Tags: blocks, registry, toolbar

My task is to show sort by panel on top and list pager at the bottom.

I tried that in the file `app/design/frontend/project/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml`

```
echo '<pre><br/>';
var_dump($this->getToolBarValue());
$this->setToolBarValue('test');
var_dump($this->getToolBarValue());
```

It returns this result:

```
false
true
false // why flase is here?
true
```

I also tried using the registry. I had the same result.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not reset. The block is cached. 
In product/list.phtml this is called `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` which is the same thing as `$this->getChildHtml('toolbar')`.
The method `getChildHtml` has 2 parameters:

```
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
```

The second parameter `$useCache` defaults to true (see Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) and is passed to `_getChildHtml()` that starts like this:

```
if ($useCache && isset($this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name])) {
            return $this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name];
        }
```

and ends like this:

```
$this->_childrenHtmlCache[$name] = $html;
```

This means that when a child html is generated is saved in a variable. Next time is requested is served from that variable. 
To avoid this, replace

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

at the bottom of the product/list.phtml with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar', false); ?>
```